# How to write a query to print the output enclosed within single quote and percentage

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT employee_id FROM employee where employee_name='SMITH';
```

Output is `76123`

How to write a query in Oracle to print the output as follows

```
'%76123%'
```

Comment: Please, show your current attempt and describe what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using concatenation is one option.

```
SQL> select chr(39) || '%' || empno || '%' ||chr(39) as result
  2  from emp
  3  where rownum = 1;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------
'%7369%'

SQL>
```

---

`chr(39)` is a single quote (simpler to use it than repeating several single quotes):

```
SQL> select '''%' || empno || '%''' as result
  2  from emp
  3  where rownum = 1;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------
'%7369%'

SQL>
```

Comment: I'm glad it did :)